# I'm getting Uncaught (in promise) Syntax Error: Unexpected end of JSON input. I am trying to GET the data and show it in my details page

Tags: reactjs, fetch, detailsview

I'm getting Uncaught (in promise) Syntax Error: Unexpected end of JSON input. I am trying to GET the data and show it in my details page. The code works with newly created items, but I have previously written data in a Json file, and  started the server with it, it shows the Json file data, but when I want to display its information(details page), it doesn't show and I get that error. The items I added after the npm start of my application work fine with the details page.
Here is my recipeService getOne(recipe) logic

```
     export const getOne = async (recipeId) => {
        return await fetch(`${baseUrl}/recipes/${recipeId}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
    }
```

Here is the recipeService getAll fetch method too

```
    export const getAll = async () => {
    let response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/recipes`)

    let recipes = await response.json();

    let result = Object.values(recipes);

    return result;
}
```

This is my Details component logic

```
   import "./Details.css";
import { Link, NavLink, useParams,useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter,Route,Routes, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import * as recipeService from "../../../services/recipeService";


const Details = () =>  {

    const [recipe,setRecipe] = useState({}); 
    const {recipeId} = useParams();
    
    const recipesd = async () => {
        let reciperes =   await recipeService.getOne(recipeId);

        setRecipe(reciperes);
    };


    useEffect(() => { recipesd(recipe); },[]);



    const history = useNavigate();
    
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    });
    
    const scrollToTop = () => {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    }

    return (
        <div>
    <section className="sec11">
        <h1>{recipe.name}</h1>
        <button smooth="true" className="leave" onClick={()=> history(-1)}><i class="fas fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
        <article className="main">
            <article className="artsm">
                <h4>Ingredients</h4>
                <p className="ingre">
                    {recipe.ingredients}
                </p>
            </article>
            <article className="artm">
                <img src={recipe.imageUrl}/>
                <hr/>
                <h4>{recipe.name}</h4>
                <p>Cooking Time: {recipe.time}min</p>
                <p className="cut-text">{recipe.instructions}</p>
            </article>
            <article className="artsm">
                <h4>Instructions</h4>
                <p className="inst">
                    {recipe.instructions}
                </p>
            </article>
        </article>
        <article className="comment">
            <form className="form">
                <textarea name="comment" placeholder=" Comment..."></textarea>
                <input className="btncom" type="submit" value="Comment"/>
            </form>
        </article>
        <button className="gob" onClick={()=> history(-1)}><i class="fas fa-solid fa-arrow-left-long"></i></button>
    </section>
        <section className="sec5navl">
        <ul>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-book-bookmark"></i></Link>Home</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/recipes"><i className="fas fa-thin fa-bowl-rice"></i></Link>Recipes</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/personal-list"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-list-ul"></i></Link>Your Recipes</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/favourites"><i className="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></Link>Favourites</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/create-recipe"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-plus"></i></Link>Add Recipe</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" to="/user-profile"><i className="fas fa-solid fa-user"></i></Link>Your Profile</li>
            <li><Link smooth= "true" onClick={scrollToTop} to={`/recipe-details/${recipe._id}`}><i class="fas fa-solid fa-arrow-up"></i></Link>Up</li>
        </ul>
        </section>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Details;
```

And thats the part of my previously defined JSON data, it gets fetched completely fine

```
   [
        {
            "_id": "62d6be17360d7443f08639d7",
            "name": "Caponata pasta",
            "time": "20",
            "imageUrl": "https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/caponata-pasta-a0027c4.jpg?resize=960,872?quality=90&webp=true&resize=375,341",
            "ingredients": "4 tbsp olive oil 1 large onion, finely chopped 4 garlic cloves, finely sliced 250g chargrilled Mediterranean veg (peppers and aubergines, if possible) from a jar, pot or deli counter, drained if in oil (you can use this oil in place of the olive oil and roughly chopped 400g can chopped tomatoes 1 tbsp small capers 2 tbsp raisins 350g rigatoni, penne or another short pasta shape bunch basil leaves, picked parmesan (or vegetarian alternative), shaved, to serve",
            "instructions": "STEP 1 Heat the oil in a large pan and cook the onion for 8-10 mins until starting to caramelise (or for longer if you have time – the sweeter the better). Add the garlic for the final 2 mins of cooking time. STEP 2 Tip in the mixed veg, tomatoes, capers and raisins. Season well and simmer, uncovered, for 10 mins, or until you have a rich sauce. STEP 3 Meanwhile, boil the kettle. Pour the kettleful of water into a large pan with a little salt and bring back to the boil. Add the pasta and cook until tender with a little bite, then drain, reserving some of the pasta water. Tip the pasta into the sauce, adding a splash of pasta water if it needs loosening. Scatter with the basil leaves and parmesan, if you like, and serve straight from the pan",
            "createdAt": "2022-07-19T14:22:15.446Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-19T14:22:15.446Z"
        }
]
```

Comment: The error indicates that the data are not getting fetched completely fine. You need to look at the network tab of your browser's developer tools and see exactly what is getting returned. It may be your server is limiting the amount of data that can be returned and is truncating the data such that it is missing ending brackets.

Comment: I have checked that. I get 200 fine and 204 no content. I have no clue on how a server works I just download and run it I don't know how to fix the issues if it has any...

Comment: Well, if you're getting 204 No Content, that indicates there would be no JSON for it to parse, and a good reason for an error regarding an unexpected end of content (right at the beginning). Not sure what you're expecting from we volunteers who don't have access to any parts of your environment to do.... I would note that `Object.values()`, in `getAll` is going to return something very different than multiples of what `getOne` returns.